# Why is e.target.files undefined when trying to use antd file upload component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Using an antd file upload component and I can't seem to access the selected files to add to the component state. I keep getting "Cannot read property 'files' of undefined". This is how I have done when using just a regular input element.

Here is the form:

```
 <Col>
          <Container className={classes.formBox}>
            <Form>
              <Upload
                type='file'
                listType='picture-card'
                onPreview={handlePreview}
                onChange={handleChange}
                multiple
              >
                {uploadButton}
              </Upload>
              <Modal>
                <img alt='example' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
              </Modal>
            </Form>
          </Container>
        </Col>
```

here is the handleChange function(this is where I get the error):

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files);
  };
```

Everything that is needed is imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Ant Design's [documentation for `Upload`](https://ant.design/components/upload/#onChange), the object passed to `onChange` has the following properties:

> ```
> {
>   file: { /* ... */ },
>   fileList: [ /* ... */ ],
>   event: { /* ... */ },
> }
> ```

> 1. `file` File object for the current operation

> ```
>  {
>    uid: 'uid',      // unique identifier, negative is recommend, to prevent interference with internal generated id
>    name: 'xx.png',   // file name
>    status: 'done', // options：uploading, done, error, removed. Intercepted file by beforeUpload don't have status field.
>    response: '{"status": "success"}', // response from server
>    linkProps: '{"download": "image"}', // additional html props of file link
>    xhr: 'XMLHttpRequest{ ... }', // XMLHttpRequest Header
> }
> ```

> 2. `fileList` current list of files
> 3. `event` response from server, including uploading progress, supported by advanced browsers

So try logging `e` and you'll find that what you're looking for is in `e.fileList`.

Comment: Thank you very much, ill be sure to read through the documentation more thoroughly!